# Remove index letters from toc

Tags: table-of-contents, indexing

I would like to remove the index letters from the toc in my master thesis. The whole index is on the same page anyway.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{report}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{doc}

 %%%%%% Indexing %%%%%%
 \IndexPrologue{\chapter*{Index}\markboth{Index}{Index}}% section heading, no message
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

%%% Begin document
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\setcounter{page}{1} 

\index{And}
\index{Book}
\index{Summer}
\index{Latex}

\pagebreak

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Index}
\printindex

\end{document}
```

Which produces this toc

[image: ToC]

Whereas I would like it to only contain the Index line, not the separate letters.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Your example code doesn't allow us to reproduce the problem (the index letters don't appear in the ToC). Please improve your code so we can reproduce the issue.

Comment: I can not reproduce this with your MWE: Are you doing something else than `pdflatex`, `makeindex`, and again `pdflatex`? Are there some definitions we need to know about? Please clear your auxiliary files and try your MWE. If you still get that output, I would be surprised.

Comment: This MWE produces something completely different but nothing similar to the screen shot

Comment: Why do you need the `doc` package? It's meant for documenting latex code/packages, not for writting at thesis

Comment: The `doc` packages is needed for other things to work and I have had trouble with it messing up things in other questions I have posted, so I included it here.

Comment: The problem that you are having with reproducing the error is likely due to that I am using a specific style, and if that is true it is the style that is the problem. Knowing this is very helpful.

The problem was solved by commenting out an `\addcontentsline` command in the `.ist` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that makeindex is configured to use special style,

`makeindex -s mystyle.ist myfile.idx`
with `mystyle.ist` something like this

```
% MakeIndex style file
heading_prefix "\\section{ "      
heading_suffix "}"  
headings_flag  1
```

The solution is to localy desable `\addcontentsline`

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{report}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{doc}

 %%%%%% Indexing %%%%%%
 \IndexPrologue{\chapter*{Index}\markboth{Index}{Index}}% section heading, no message
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

%%% Begin document
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\setcounter{page}{1} 

\index{And}
\index{Book}
\index{Summer}
\index{Latex}

\pagebreak

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Index}

{\def\addcontentsline#1#2#3{} %<---
\printindex}                  %<---

\end{document}
```